# Why do 2 same numbers written in slightly form produce 2 different outcomes in Java

Tags: java, math

I successfully managed to solve a math problem using Java code. However, in doing so, I've also stumbled upon something weird.

In one of my calculations, I had to add 4 numbers: 13, 132, 320, and 201. I declared an int variable sum, and initialized it to 13 + 132 + 320 + 201.

```
int sum = 13 + 132 + 320 + 201;
```

When I printed the variable sum out, it returned a value of 666. Which makes sense, since adding those numbers on a calculator returns that value. However, I decided to then set the variable sum equal to something a little different. I decided to set sum equal to 013 + 132 + 320 + 201.

```
sum = 013 + 132 + 320 + 201;
```

However, when I printed this value out, I got 664. I decided to add one more zero to the left of 013.

```
sum = 0013 + 132 + 320 + 201;
```

And sum returned the same value, 664.

So basically, whenever I add the numbers just like that without any unnecessary zeroes, sum returns the correct value. But when I add those unecessary zeroes, sum returns a slightly different answer. Is there a reason as to why putting zeroes before a number causes a slightly different result?

Comment: Because when you added that zero, Java interpreted that number as an octal value, not decimal.

Comment: Octal. 013 is octal. Aargh you lag, too late the party

Comment: Just to give the math bit: `013` == `11.0` == `0b1011` == `0xB` == `1.1e1`

Comment: @r3mainer that's for python. This question is about Java

Comment: @phuclv I know, but the solution is identical.

Comment: @r3mainer no you can't close with a solution in a different language. There are already lots of duplicates in Java to close

Answer (score 3):

**In math only base is not decimal .So to define numbers in base 16(Hexa-decimal),8(Octal),2(Binary) and 10(Decimal) there must be a way.So in java you can define those like below.**

Adding the **prefix** of **0b or 0B** you can define **binary numbers (base 2)**

`byte b1 = 0b101;`

Adding the **prefix** of **0** you can define **octal numbers(base 8)**

`int octal = 013;`

Adding the **prefix** of **0x** you can define **hexa decimal numbers(base 16)**

`int hexaDecimal =0x13;`

**You can define decimal numbers without using any prefix**

`int decimal = 13;`

Answer (score 1):

Your question is basically this:

```
// Java interprets this as octal number
int octal = 013;
// Java interprets this as hexadecimal number
int hexa = 0x13
// Java interprets this as decimal number
int decimal = 13
```

Comment: So basically, adding zeroes before a number, while they mean the same thing in math, actually changes the base of the number? So 013 is 13 with a base of 8? And 0013 is 0x13 which is 13 with a base of 6?